# Parsing json into data structures with lower case field names

Tags: json, transformation, abap

I am parsing JSON into ABAP structures, and it works:

```
DATA cl_oops TYPE REF TO cx_dynamic_check.
DATA(text) = `{"TEXT":"Hello ABAP, I'm JSON!","CODE":"123"}`.
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_structure,
         text TYPE string,
         code TYPE char3,
       END OF ty_structure.
DATA : wa_structure TYPE ty_structure.
TRY.
    text = |\{"DATA":{ text }\}|.
    CALL TRANSFORMATION id OPTIONS clear = 'all' 
         SOURCE XML text 
         RESULT data = wa_structure.
    WRITE: wa_structure-text , wa_structure-code.
  CATCH cx_transformation_error INTO cl_oops.
    WRITE cl_oops->get_longtext( ).
ENDTRY.
```

The interesting part is that the CODE and TEXT are case sensitive. For most external systems, having all CAPS identifiers is ugly, so I have been trying to parse `{"text":"Hello ABAP, I'm JSON!","code":"123"}` without any success. I looked into the options, I looked whether a changed copy of `id` migh accomplish this, I googled it and have no idea how to accomplish this.

Comment: the only thing I could find is a note in the SAP help page for call transformation. It seems that if you define the source or result structure dynamically, the case specified there is used. Otherwise, uppercase is used. http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abapcall_transformation.htm

Comment: Is creating as simple transformation and using it in place of standard `ID` an option for you? If so, then maybe [this article](http://sapblog.rmtiwari.com/2009/04/generate-simple-transformation-for-xml.html) will be helpful. It is about `XML` but the transformation will remain the same no matter if you use `XML` or `JSON`, so I think you could easily adapt it to your needs. It is shown there how to obtain lower case for node names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that SAP has a [sample program on how to do this.](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abenabap_json_names_to_upper_abexa.htm)
There is basically an out of the box transformation that does this for you called `demo_json_xml_to_upper`. The name is a bit unfortunate, so I would suggest renaming this transformation and adding it to the customer namespace.

I am a bit bummed that this only works through xstrings, so debugging it becomes a pain. But, it works perfeclty and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this is low tech. I spent hours looking for a simple way to get out of this mess that the JSON response could have the fieldnames in lower or camel case. Here it is: if you know the field names - obviously you do because your table has the same column names - just replace the lower case name with an upper case one in your xstring.
If in your table the field is USERS_ID and in the JSON xstring it is users_ID - go for that:

```
replace all occurrences of 'users_ID' in ls_string with 'USERS_ID'.
```

Do the same for all fields and the object name and call transformation ID.

Comment: It’s all fun until you uppercase COUNTRY and your long texts have uppercase COUNTRY where they should not have.

Comment: That's right of course - it might not work in every situation. You could include the " - replace all occurrences of '"users_ID"' in ls_string with '"USERS_ID"'. That should be pretty save.